# Как выстроить график по groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть Dataset недвижимости.

```
new4 = new2.groupby(['SaleCondition', 'YrSold'])[['SalePrice']].count()
```

Как эти данные вывести в любой график?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/152H-TILAnZJnh6n_K61V4CgR5dICj6sk/view?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "любой график"? Любой вы можете построить просто с помощью `new2.plot()`. Вам какой нужен?

Comment: Не додумалась, что так просто можно. Чтобы наглядно было видно количество по SaleCondition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если наглядно нужно, то делайте `unstack`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', index_col='Id')
df1 = df.groupby(['SaleCondition', 'YrSold'])[['SalePrice']].count()
df1.unstack().plot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]